# How to generate Dart from GraphQL - graphql to dart generator

Tags: flutter, dart, types, graphql, code-generation

**How can simple object types [1] such as interfaces &/ classes be generated from GraphQL schema definitions into Dart?**

- Motivation

  - One single source of truth: GraphQL schema
  - From GraphQL all plain simple types are generated into multiple languages

    - in our case Typescript and Dart
- what we've tried so far

  - All solutions related [2] - even forks - does not do simple types
- Possible DIY approaches we know of

  - GraphQL Code Generator [3]
  - quicktype similar alternatives [4]

### GraphQL into Typescript example

#### Given this schema definition

```
type Person {
    age: Int
    name: String!
}
```

#### Running this script

```
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';


const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();

definitionsFactory.generate({
    typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    path: join(process.cwd(), './class.ts'),
    outputAs: 'class'
});

definitionsFactory.generate({
    typePaths: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
    path: join(process.cwd(), './interface.ts'),
    outputAs: 'interface'
});
```

#### Output

```
export interface Person {
    age?: number;
    name: string;
}
```

```
export class Person {
    age?: number;
    name: string;
}
```

1: Simple Object Types should be just simple plain object types without annotations, encoding and decoding logic etc.
2: https://github.com/gql-dart/gql
3: https://graphql-code-generator.com
4: https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: You can try my package [graphql_to_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_to_dart). Its a work in progress but works well for output types.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so incredibly fast and also thank you for this package, we will put our question in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally tried to use [Artemis](https://github.com/kateile/artemis) or hoped [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/) was branching out, but [@Ryosuke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10336633/ryosuke)'s [graphql_to_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_to_dart) is straight forward and lean.

If you already have a GraphQL endpoint with your schema up and running, you just need to set up its `graphql_config.yaml` for example like this:

```
package_name: example
graphql_endpoint: http://example.com/graphql
models_directory_path: lib/graphql/models/
```

#### Given schema definition

```
type Person {
    age: Int
    name: String!
}
```

#### .dart Output

```
class Person{
  int age;
  String name;
  Person({
    this.age,this.name
  });

  Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    age = json['age'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map toJson(){
    Map _data = {};
    _data['age'] = age;
    _data['name'] = name;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

With the additional option `type_override` you can set custom scalar types as you prefer them.

Edit:

There is now an [expanded version](https://github.com/hermann-w/graphql_to_dart/tree/1-no-dynamic-import-paths-option) as [PR](https://github.com/vikram25897/graphql_to_dart/pull/2).
With the possibility to generate them outside of `lib/` without import path conflicts, through an opt-out option `dynamic_import_path: false`.

The `type_override` keys also don't need to be explicitly written in lower case anymore.